# table row is not expand to full width in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I try to hide/show columns for different width, i do that however after that i have a problem with table width !

If first resolution is smaller then second, table row not set to full width (for ex : load page in portrait phone with 320×480 and then rotate phone to landscape to 480*320) however that work fine if first load is in landscape!

[image: sample pic]

here is my html code :

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="box">
            <header>
                <div class="icons"><i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i></div>
                <h5>Project List</h5>
            </header>
            <div id="collapse4" class="body">
                <table id="dataTable" class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover table-striped" >
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="hide-col1">ID</th>
                        <th >Name</th>
                        <th >Category</th>
                        <th class="hide-col3">Type</th>
                        <th class="hide-col2">Owner</th>
                        <th class="hide-col3">Pages</th>
                        <th class="hide-col4">Translator</th>
                        <th >Status</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="hide-col1">1</td>
                                <td>sample name</td>
                                <td >English</td>
                                <td class="hide-col3">Normal</td>
                                <td class="hide-col2">Sarah</td>
                                <td class="hide-col3">20</td>
                                <td class="hide-col4">Mehrdad H</td>
                                <td> sample btn </td>
                            </tr>

                    </tbody>                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and css :

```
@media  (max-width : 900px){
    .hide-col1{
        display: none;
      }
}
@media  (max-width : 850px){
    .hide-col2{
        display: none;
      }
}
@media  (max-width: 550px){
    .hide-col3{
        display: none ;
      }
}
@media (max-width: 360px){
    .hide-col4{
        display: none;
      }
}
```

whats wrong ?

**Update :**

Also i try `table-layout: fixed` and `width: 100%;`

Sample code :

```
@media (max-width: 360px){
    .hide-col4{
        display: none;
      }
    #dataTable
    {
        table-layout: fixed;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

also when i remove `class="hide-col*"` from `th`, `td` all works fine !

sample :
Change

```
<th class="hide-col3">
```

to

```
<th >
```

Comment: I created a fiddle and it's working fine https://jsfiddle.net/ArefBenLazrek/p2rppk9b/ maybe you have other css causing problem, and you can use bootstrap table-responsive class instead of hiding cols

Comment: @عارفبنالأزرق thanks for answer, you right i think that's because of my data table, i try to solve that.....

Comment: post your full code then we will help you.